# Remove block of text stored in one file from another file

Tags: sed, grep, text-processing

I have few tens of GB file. It contains repeating block of code I want to remove. I will copy this block of code into file named `toBeRemoved` and I'd like to run some command, without knowing internal structure of either file and remove all lines *to be removed* from *huge* file. The main requirement is not having to analyze block of text *to be removed*, so that you have just do

`someCommand {anyNumberOfParameters} {fileWithBlockOfTextToBeRemoved} {fileToRemoveFrom}`

do we have such *someCommand*?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally found the answer:

```
pcregrep -v -F -f <(seq 2 4) <(for J in {1..5};do seq 5;done)
```

for the large files you need to raise buffer.

Comment: well ... depsite of unexplained negative voting, this works and better than most answers here. Marking as a valid answer. I hope it will help someone as it did me.